# Implementing BufferStrategy

Tags: java, android, animation, bufferstrategy

I'm coming from Java background and for creating games I always used BufferStrategy for smoothing animations. However in Android I couldn't find BufferStrategy, so I decided to create my own. How would you implement a BufferStrategy? Pseudo-code is also ok, but I prefer a code in Android of course.

Comment: BufferStrategy in the broadest sense is simply an abstraction of related os functionalities and as such can not be implemented by yourself.

Comment: ?? I'm using BufferStrategy in my Java apps. It's really straightforward. What do you mean?